# like clause in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to include like clause in the case of last_name.This is my controller code used for search box.I want to compare form value last_name with db value family_name.

```
public function filtered_volunteer_details()
{
    $user_data = $this->session->userdata("logged_user");
    $tab_result = array();
    if (is_array($user_data) && $user_data["user_role"] == "staff")
    {
        if ($this->input->method() == "post")
        {
            $condition = array();
            $data = $this->input->post();
            if(isset($data["membership_number"]) && $data["membership_number"]!= "")
            {
                $condition["membership_number"]=trim($data["membership_number"]);
            }
            if(isset($data["last_name"]) && $data["last_name"]!= "")
            {
                $condition["family_name "]=trim($data["last_name"]);
            }

            $this->load->model(array(
                "Users"));
            $result = $this->Users->get_volunteers("*",$condition);
            $volunteer_tbl_list=array();
            foreach($result as $volunteer_results)
            {
            $volunteer_tbl_list[] = $this->load->view("staff/manage_volunteer/volunteer_list_tbl_row",  $volunteer_results, TRUE);  
            }
            echo json_encode(array(
            "status" => "success",
            "volunteer_tbl_list" => $volunteer_tbl_list));
            return;
        }
    }

    echo json_encode(array(
        "error" => "true",
        "msg" => "Invalid Access."));
    return;
}
```

This is my model code

```
public function get_volunteers($fields = "*",$condition=array())
{
    $condition["staff"]="N";
    $this->db->select($fields);
    $query = $this->db->get_where(self::$tbl_name, $condition);
    //var_dump($this->db->last_query());
    return( $query->result() );
}
```

Comment: can you post ypur model code??

Comment: can you add model code?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `$this->db->like()` to the query in `get_volunteers()`. [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-similar-data)

```
public function get_volunteers($fields = "*",$condition=array())
{
    $condition["staff"]="N";
    $this->db->select($fields);
    $this->db->like($condition);
    $this->db->from(self::$tbl_name);
    return( $query->result() );
}
```